# Android: change Checkbox background Color without changing the text color

Tags: android, checkbox

checkBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

will change the background color of the whole element. I want only the Square. Is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `android:button="@drawable/bg_checkbox"` or `checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.bg_checkbox);`

Comment: i dont like to set a background image because it does not scale with element. is there not a native method?